# How to link downloadable files in docusaurus?

Tags: reactjs, web, docusaurus

I want to link downloadable content on my documentation and I tried putting in a link like this:

```
<a
  href={
    require("@site/static/img/04-api/01/API-Description.png")
      .default
  } download="file-name"
>  download </a>
```

This generates following html:

```
<a download="file-name" href="/assets/images/API-Description-6aeb65d8ae136a70b1b5a3d916d27ca0.png">  download </a>

<a download="file-name" href="/assets/images/API-Description-6aeb65d8ae136a70b1b5a3d916d27ca0.png">  download </a>
```

When I click on the link, I get

> "Page Not Found"

I am running version: 2.0.0-beta.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to use inline-html with the `download` attribute and `target="_blank"`

```
[not working](/logo.png)

<a href={ require("/logo.png").default } download={"origName"}>not working</a>

<a target="_blank" href={ require("/logo.png").default } download>working</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found two ways of doing this.

**First,** put the file inside the `static` folder. 
Example: `./static/image.png`.

**1) Your way**

```
<a href={ require("/image.png").default }>download</a>
```

**2) Simple way**

```
[download](/image.png)
```

** Note that we did not use the `!` to indicate that is an image.

Comment: I tried it again with you both of your ways, sadly it's still not working. Same error: "Page Not Fount". 

Is there maybe some configuration i must do beforehand, so docusaurus is even able to make something downloadable?

Comment: Try to clear the cache: 1) stop the docusaurus service. 2) Open the terminal in the folder of your website. 3) Run `npx docusaurus clear`. 4) Start the docusaurus service.

Comment: Also, I simplified the example. Insert an image inside the `static` folder, then use the example to see if any change happens. Also, note that in the second example there is no `"` delimiting the image's path.

Comment: It still didnt work. But i figured it out. I just had to add target="_blank" and **download** to the inline html

Comment: Good to known! I suggest that you post your solution as an `Answer`, and accept it. It could helps others in the future.

Comment: Oh okay, I will do that. I am still quite new to Stackoverflow  :D